# WPF: Styling radio buttons into a square

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application where I need the user to pick one and only one corner of an onscreen box.

[image: Sample box with lower left corner selected]

It makes sense to me that the type of button would be a radio button. Exactly one corner can be selected at a time.

But, Radio buttons are naturally round in Windows and WPF.  But WPF allows someone to restyle the UI elements, if they understand how.

Can someone show me how this could be restyled. I would like to see it done in a way that would not affect the look of the other radio buttons in the same window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To style the `RadioButton` the way you want it, you'll need to change its `ControlTemplate` to a custom one. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/radiobutton-styles-and-templates) has a sample `ControlTemplate`. I've adapted it so that the `RadioButton` shows up as a square. It's a simplified `ControlTemplate` in that it has no animations:

```
<Style x:Key="SquareRadioButton" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource RadioButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="Border"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                Stroke="Black"
                                Fill="White"
                                />
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="CheckMark"
                                Fill="Black"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Margin="2"
                                />
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.Color"
                                        >
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                                        >
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                        >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                        />
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can then apply it to the `RadioButton` you want to style:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource SquareRadioButton}" Content="Option 1" />
```